# Troubleshooting app.config After Database Migration

Tags: database, vb.net, connection-string, app-config

[image: Error Message Screenshot]

My client has a Windows application called "checkbook.exe" written in VB.NET.  The source code is no longer available.  There is an app.config file with the database connection string in it.  This has worked for several years.  My client's hosting company moved their database and provided a new IP.  We updated the IP address in the app.config and got the "connectionstring property has not been initialized" error.

I connected to the database with SQL-Server Management Studio using the new IP and the old id/password.  That tells me they are correct.  I checked the app.config for obvious typos and found none.  So far, all of the articles about this topic point to a problem in the source code.  What else could be the problem?

Comment: And are you sure it uses the connection from App.config which properly should be called: checkbook.exe.config.

Comment: Yes.  The file on disk is called checkbook.exe.config.  Thanks for helping.

Comment: may be the needed ports are not open ...

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issue of the ports?  I was able to connect with SSMS.

Comment: Maybe the actual connection string is hard-coded in the app. You could try a decompiler such as http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/ and see if you can get to it.

Comment: @Simon...  That's a good suggestion.  I know the connection string is in the config file but I suppose it could also be hard-coded.  I'll look into that.

Comment: I can't install that decompiler until I have access to a different machine but it looks like @Simon may be correct.  If so, how do I mark his response as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the actual connection string is hard-coded in the app. You could try a decompiler such as [JetBrains decompiler](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) and see if you can get to it.